# Gradle look into wrong maven repository l

Tags: java, maven, gradle, repository, asyncapi

How I add plugin in build.gradle.
Source: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.asyncapi.asyncapi-gradle-plugin

```
 buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("com.asyncapi:asyncapi-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-EAP.1")
  }
}

apply(plugin = "com.asyncapi.asyncapi-gradle-plugin")
```

I get error:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'java-backend'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.asyncapi:asyncapi-core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/asyncapi/asyncapi-core/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/asyncapi/asyncapi-core/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/asyncapi-core-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
     Required by:
         project : > com.asyncapi:asyncapi-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-EAP.1 > com.asyncapi:asyncapi-plugin-core:1.0.0-EAP

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

the repository must be searched by path https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/asyncapi/asyncapi-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-EAP.1/ ...Why is he looking for another way?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it from `1.0.0-EAP.1` to `1.0.0-EAP-1`. If it doesn't works, it's also available on [mvncentral](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.asyncapi.asyncapi-gradle-plugin/com.asyncapi.asyncapi-gradle-plugin.gradle.plugin/1.0.0-EAP-1).